# This While loop is Driving me Crazy

Tags: php, sql, database, loops, while-loop

I want to simply display something using a while loop with php, but it is not working.

Here is the code -

```
<?php 

mysqli_select_db($connect,"users");

$select_title = "select title, message from messages where user = '$u' LIMIT 4 ";

$querying = mysqli_query($connect,$select_title) or die ('Whops! Something went wrong.');

$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);

    //$title = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect,trim($line['title']));

while(($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying)))
{

    echo $rows['title'];
}
```

?>

Now I have two titles, but only one is being displayed. Why so?

Comment: because one is sitting and waiting for you in "$line"? Try removing that line... (no pun intended)

Comment: Have you tied replacing echo $rows['title']; with something like echo 'test'?  Does the loop actually loop twice?

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` takes a string, and the old method of passing in your resource handler is depreciated. so you can remove the `$connect` variable

Answer (score 6):

You have fetched one row here:

```
$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);
```

The cursor will be moved to the next row, hence

```
while(($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying)))
{

    echo $rows['title'];
}
```

will display the second row only.

The best solution is simply comment that line:

```
 //$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete this line:

```
$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);
```

Answer (score 1):

Comment this line will solve your problem

```
//$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);
```

Answer (score 1):

... because you fetch the first title with the line `$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);` but never echo it and then start a loop to go through the rest of the titles.

Delete/uncomment the line and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

you already fetch one record with

```
$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);
```

so there is only one left in while

Answer (score 0):

### Debug

My MySQL is a bit rusty(Long time ago since I used SQL => Moved to NoSQL camp...), but this is what I would do:

- First I would test if query returns correct result using phpmyadmin console or just mysql console from commandline.

But I guess the query is correct because a lot of people are saying that

```
$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);
```

is already fetching a row. But still you could use it for debugging purposes I guess.

### PDO

Also I would like to point out you should [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) instead of mysqli(almost deprecated I guess). PDO prepared statements also protect you against SQL-injections and could be faster because it is precompiled.

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` you "take" one record from the result set. When there are no more records, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` returns false. This is, by the way, the reason you can use `while` loop.

When you called `$line = mysqli_fetch_assoc($querying);`, you took one record from the result set, leaving only 1 in the result set. So your `while` loop iterates over this one record only. As everyone else pointed out - you just need to comment that line.

I can also recommend using `mysqli_fetch_all()` [function](http://ee.php.net/mysqli_fetch_all), this will give you an ordinary array that you can use, well, like a normal array

```
$results = mysqli_fetch_all($querying, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```